# How to reverse on two conditions under an apache reverse proxy

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy

I'm new on apache reverse proxy, and I trying to reverse Url calling like bellow:

[image]

I'm able to forward all request on Webserver1 like that:

> 

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>  

 ProxyPreserveHost On  
 ServerName localhost  
 ProxyPass / http://webserver1/  
 ProxyPassReverse / http://webserver1/  
 </VirtualHost>
```

But I'm not able to make condition on Url Param example:

If **"http://reverse.proxy.com/?param=foo"** then forwarding it to **WebServer 2**

And also, I don't know if those rules could be on the Same configuration.

Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution to do like that.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ProxyPreserveHost On
ServerName localhost

RewriteEngine on
logLevel warn rewrite:trace3

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^param=(.*)
RewriteRule (.*) http://Webserver2/?param=%1? [P]

ProxyPassMatch / http://Webserver1
ProxyPassReverse / http://Webserver1

</VirtualHost>
```

it seems working fine

Answer (score 0):

You should try this once..

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName localhost
RewriteEngine  on
ProxyPass / http://webserver1/
ProxyPassReverse / http://webserver1/
RewriteRule    "^/foo.html$"  "bar.html"  [R]

Comment: Hi Arjun,

Many thank for your help, I tried to set your configuration, but apache crashed on startup due to syntax error:

`AH00526: Syntax error on line 22 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/00-Rev_proxy.conf:`

is relative to this line:

`ProxyPassReverse / http://webserver1/ RewriteRule "^/foo.html$" "bar.html" [R]`

Comment: An other point, As I wrote on the top of my post (please have a look on schema on the top), I want to forward all request which had an Url parameters to webserver 2 like below:

`www.yoursite.com?myparam={id}`